# Can I git-svn clone an svn repo with multiple standard directory layouts

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I have an SVN repo with a layout like
project1/trunk
project1/branches
project1/tags
project2/trunk
project2/branches
project2/tags
etc.

For a number of reasons, I'd like a git-svn repo that allows me to work on any of these projects and fetch/dcommit from/to all of them at once. Is this kind of thing possible? I know I could just git-svn clone the whole thing without specifying branches, tags, and trunk, but then I'd lose a lot of the advantage of using git.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I did it.  There may be simpler ways, though.

1. Select the first project with the standard layout you'd like to work on and `git svn clone` it:

   `git svn clone --stdlayout http://sample.com/svn/repository-name/project-name repository-name`
2. Go into the `repository-name` directory and edit its `.git/config` file.  You could also do this with `git-config` commands, but I find it easier in a text editor.
3. You'll see an `[svn-remote "svn"]` section already defined for your first project.  Rename the `svn-remote` to something more unique than `"svn"`, probably the same as your project name.  E.g., `[svn-remote "project-name"]`.
4. Make more `[svn-remote "project-name"]` sections for each project, following the template of the first one.  Give each one a unique name!  You'll need to change the `fetch`, `branches`, and `tags` settings to use the correct Subversion directory names for each project.
5. Once you're done, save your file and run `git svn fetch --fetch-all`.  The other projects will be fetched as remotes in your local repository.
6. To switch your `master` between projects, do a `git reset --hard other-project-name/trunk`, just like if you were switching to work on any other remote Subversion branch.

Comment: Will a git svn rebase rebase all of the projects? Will a git svn dcommit commit all the changes?

Comment: `git svn rebase` just gets you revisions for your current HEAD, so no, all you get is the current branch on the current project.  Same for `git svn dcommit`.  To get every project you need to do a `git svn fetch --fetch-all` and then rebase your current HEAD.  Unfortunately I don't know of an equivalent to commit all local branches that are ahead of their remotes, but I'm sure it could be scripted.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. To simplify, in step 1 add -R project1-name --prefix=project1-name/ to the git svn clone command to have the initial clone use the right svn-remote name and branch prefixes from the start.

Comment: @MarkGardner: But you have to switch between projects, right? You cannot have all projects checked out simultaneously?

Comment: Correct, that's what step 6 above says.

Answer (score 1):

To get around the issue of checking out multiple projects simultaneously, 
git-new-workdir can be used to check out multiple working directories from the same git repository, see https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/workdir/git-new-workdir